# Find file's parent id : Google Drive API V3

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, drive

[image]

Today after I updated my Drive API to V3, I dint find any method to find the parent of the selected file . Is the rest endpoint to fetch json related to parent's info changed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have the file id of the file in question then [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.get) you need to add fields ie parents along with the file id.

Request

> GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B5pJkOVaKccENWNNcFFaU2lSM0E?fields=parents&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Returns

> {  "parents": [   "0B5pJkOVaKccEYW5lVHBKd1Zwc28"  ] }

The result is actually a file id.  Remember files and directories are the same in Drive.

Do files.get again

> GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B5pJkOVaKccEYW5lVHBKd1Zwc28?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Results

> {  "kind": "drive#file",  "id": "0B5pJkOVaKccEYW5lVHBKd1Zwc28", 
>   "name": "SiteBackups",  "mimeType":
>   "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" }

Comment: The links of documentation you are pointing to is of Google Drive V2. [Google Drive V3](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/) doesn't have method like parent().list() etc

Comment: What language are you using?   V3 I think is only for android and ios I think. I am going to have to dig in some other documentation for that.

Comment: Both java and javascript are used based on suitability. Are the remaining methods coming in later revisions or are they going to be deprecated?

Comment: Updated for v3: Its weird that there is no true documentation site for V3. I need to see if I can figure out why that is.

Comment: Works perfectly in javascript. But how to set partial field mask "parent" using java api?. Or should I have to make rest call from there also like I am doing in javascript

Comment: if you find the java client library for drive v3 it should support it.  However I am not sure its a discovery api which means it probably hasn't been generated for the Java client library.  Its not generated for the .net client library.   You can still send the rest requests manually.

Answer (score 9):

**Congrats, you found the Google Drive API version 3 several hours before we [officially announced it](https://goo.gl/vh4ceS). :)**

In v3, there is no longer a parents collection. Instead, you get the parents property by doing a [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) with the child's ID. Ideally, you would use the [fields parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/performance#partial) to restrict the response to just the parent(s). Note: A file may have more than one parent, so be prepared to handle multiple parents.

You can get a sense of the changes from v2 to v3 by looking at the [migration cheat sheet](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration).

Comment: So you guys removed the ability to get a list of files containing a specific child `fileId`? `fileId in children`? Why? Now we have to make a call to the fileId, get an array of parentIds, then make a separate call to get those files. More cumbersome.

Comment: You would have to do that anyway, the old method only returned you a list of fileIDs as well. Also, you don't have to move to v3 and can happily stay on v2 if you feel you need to.

Comment: The old way, we could call `/files` with a `:fileId in children` and it would return a collection of `DriveFile` objects (fully expanded, as is std for that endpoint) who are parents of that fileId. One call.

Comment: That was never a feature in the API. I'm no longer on Drive but reached out to them to get an answer on your question.

Comment: No way to get trashed file's parents when responding to deletion events.

Comment: @DanMcGrath - "migration cheat sheet" link is giving a 404 response

Comment: @DanMcGrath - "I'm no longer on Drive but reached out to them to get an answer on your question" - I know this question is 3 years old, but did someone from the Drive team respond?

Comment: Just an update, I've tested python code that references `'parents':['parent-folder-id'],` in v3 and it seems to work now (only tested with folder open to public)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the SDK to do it

```
        $service    = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

        // Print the names and IDs.
        $optParams = array(
            'fields'    => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, fileExtension, trashed, webViewLink, mimeType, ownedByMe, parents, fileExtension, webContentLink)',
            'q'         => $folderId . " in parents" // pass the folder id as a string to the variable $folderId
        );

        $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
        $results = $results->getFiles();
```

Comment: There is a mistake here, you need ticks in $folderId. In PHP, something like the following :  $query = '\'' . $folderId . '\' in parents';

Answer (score 0):

[image]

use it like the bellow

```
let fileMetadata = {
    'name': new Date()+'-dbBackup.zip',
    'parents':  [  '1193XW7zIzQHZHRIzkYzbFqwDC-ruGb-TE'  ]
};
```