# Google Drive API v3 (googleapiclient.errors.HttpError 404 File not found)

Tags: python, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to upload a pdf file created on my computer with path `output_pdfs/<pdf-name>.pdf`. I'm using the `id` of the parent folder of where I want to upload the files to in my code. I'm getting an HttpError 404 "File Not Found .", referring to the parent ID (parent folder). I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34279002) I can get the parentID by using the childID but that doesn't work as I want to create a sub-folder (child) because it might not exist yet.

Steps I've done:

1. Shared the Google Drive folder with the service account and set it to "Content Manager"
2. Added auth scopes for my service account in my python code `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"`
3. Ensured that my gcloud credentials are set correctly, `gcloud auth list` shows I'm using the same credentials that I shared the sheet with.

```
def deliver_to_google_drive(output_pdf, creds, parentFolderID, folderToCreate):
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    file_metadata = {
        'parents':[parentFolderID],
        'name': output_pdf
    }
    media = MediaFileUpload(output_pdf, mimetype='application/pdf',resumable=True)
    file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, """<-- 404 error here"""
                                        media_body=media,
                                        fields='id').execute() 
    print('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
    file.Upload()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload file to google drive with service account credential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49663359/how-to-upload-file-to-google-drive-with-service-account-credential)

Comment: Nikko J. apologies on the late response. Not really because I've already shared the folder with the service account email address.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So because the folder's in a shared drive, when listing parent folders you need to use `includeItemsFromAllDrives=True` and `supportsAllDrives=True` and use `supportsAllDrives=True` again when creating the file. I've tested this code which finds parent folders by name, creates a file and uploads it

```
def deliver_to_google_drive(output_pdf, creds, folderToStorePdfs):
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    page_token = None
    while True:
        query = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name = '%s'" % folderToStorePdfs
        response = drive_service.files().list(q=query,
                                              spaces='drive',
                                              fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                              includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
                                              supportsAllDrives=True,
                                              pageToken=page_token).execute()
                                              #NB includeItemsFromAllDrives and supportsAllDrives needed for shared drives
        for folder in response.get('files', []):
            print('Found folder: %s (%s)' % (folder.get('name'), folder.get('id')))
            print(output_pdf)
            filename = output_pdf.split('/')[1]

            file_metadata = {
                'parents':[folder.get('id')],
                'name': filename
            }
            media = MediaFileUpload(output_pdf, mimetype='application/pdf',resumable=True)
            file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                                media_body=media,
                                                fields='id',supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
            print('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if page_token is None:
            break
```