# Get folder id by folder name

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive2

I would like to find folder_id by using a folder name to search in your Google Drive.

```
Error: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=%27None%27+and+trashed%3Dfalse&maxResults=1000&supportsAllDrives=true&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&alt=json returned "File not found:". Details: "[{'message': 'File not found: ', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'location': 'file', 'locationType': 'other'}]">
```

Here is my current part of the script that fails. I start to wonder if it is even possible to search for a certain folder by name.

```py
def get_folder_id_by_name(self, drive, folder_name):
        file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false"}).GetList()
        for file in file_list:
            if file['title'] == folder_name:
                return file['id']
            return None

if not self.backup:
    # Use self.options['backup_folder'] as the folder ID where backups are stored
    backup_folder_name = self.options['backup_folder']
    backup_folder_id = self.get_folder_id_by_name(self.drive, backup_folder_name)

    if not backup_folder_id:
    # If the folder doesn't exist, create it
        folder = self.drive.CreateFile({'title': backup_folder_name, 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'})
        folder.Upload()
        backup_folder_id = folder['id']
        print(f"Created folder '{backup_folder_name}' with ID: {backup_folder_id}")
```

Comment: read [this](https://docs.iterative.ai/PyDrive2/)

Comment: Yeah read that, but I've probably gone blind as a bat. I don't see it.

Comment: haha, let me see what I can find for you

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68084688/6651840) they have using v3 of the drive library, your library is v2 and is no longer supported

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/PyDrive2/

It is actively maintained, latest update is from august 15th.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in order to search the folder using the folder name, the folder name can be included in the search query. So, in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```py
def get_folder_id_by_name(self, drive, folder_name):
        file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false"}).GetList()
        for file in file_list:
            if file['title'] == folder_name:
                return file['id']
            return None
```

#### To:

```py
def get_folder_id_by_name(self, drive, folder_name):
    file_list = drive.ListFile(
        {'q': "title='" + folder_name + "' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false"}).GetList()
    if file_list != []:
        return file_list[0]['id']
    return None
```

- If you want to search the folder by including the shared drive, please modify it as follows.

  ```py
  def get_folder_id_by_name(self, drive, folder_name):
      file_list = drive.ListFile(
          {
              'q': "title='" + folder_name + "' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false",
              'corpora': 'allDrives',
              'includeItemsFromAllDrives': True,
              'supportsAllDrives': True,
          }).GetList()
      if file_list != []:
          return file_list[0]['id']
      return None
  ```
- In the case of PyDrive2, `title` is used for searching the file and folder name because of Drive API v2. [Ref](https://github.com/iterative/PyDrive2)

#### Reference:

- [Search query terms and operators](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms)

### Added:

About your following reply,

> Maybe I forgot to include: The folder it is searching for does NOT exist, so it has to create the folder. I know it can find the folder if I manually create it in my Google Drive.

I couldn't notice about this from your question. So, if you want to create a new folder when the folder name does not exist, how about the following modification?

```py
def get_folder_id_by_name(self, drive, folder_name):
    file_list = drive.ListFile(
        {
            'q': "title='" + folder_name + "' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false",
            'corpora': 'allDrives',
            'includeItemsFromAllDrives': True,
            'supportsAllDrives': True,
        }).GetList()
    if file_list != []:
        return file_list[0]['id']
    folder = drive.CreateFile({'title': folder_name, "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"})
    folder.Upload()
    return folder['id']
```

- When this script is run with `folder_name`, when the folder name is not existing, a new folder is created. From your reply and question, I couldn't know the parent folder you want to create. So, in this case, the new folder is created in the root folder.
- If you want to create a new folder in the specific parent folder, please modify it as follows.

  ```py
  folder = drive.CreateFile({'title': folder_name, "parents": [{"id": "### parent folder ID ###"}], "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"})
  ```

Comment: Right, I'll try this. I also solved an error, I had somehow 2 the same files being loaded from different places. They were conflicting each other of course. The error I'm now facing is about the query, so I hope your solution works. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: ```Error: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=%271n_7-tyjIjpc2JkIMI_W_xWuEXGleVDc1%27+and+trashed%3Dfalse&maxResults=1000&supportsAllDrives=true&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&alt=json returned "Invalid query". Details: "[{'message': 'Invalid query', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'q', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">
```

I got this error now. There is something about the query going wrong.

Comment: Maybe I forgot to include:

The folder it is searching for does NOT exist, so it has to create the folder. I know it can find the folder if I manually create it in my Google Drive.

Comment: If I edit it like this:
`{'q': "'"+folder_name+"' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false"}).GetList()`


` Error: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=%27PwnagotchiBackups%27+in+parents+and+mimeType%3D%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%27+and+trashed%3Dfalse&maxResults=1000&supportsAllDrives=true&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&alt=json returned "File not found:". Details: "[{'message': 'File not found: ', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'location': 'file', 'locationType': 'other'}]">`

Comment: @Jeroen Oudshoorn Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. About `Maybe I forgot to include: The folder it is searching for does NOT exist, so it has to create the folder. I know it can find the folder if I manually create it in my Google Drive.`, I couldn't notice it. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. So, I added one more modified script in my answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your actual expected result, I apologize again.

Comment: Yeah thank you, but I am creating a new folder outside the get_folder_id_by_name function.
It is there in my first post.

Comment: @Jeroen Oudshoorn Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `but I am creating a new folder outside the get_folder_id_by_name function. It is there in my first post.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?